# The solution to $y'=y^2(x-y)$ with $y(0)=1$ blows up in finite time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Show that the solution to the ODE $y'=y^2(x-y)$ with initial value $y(0)=1$ cannot be continued to the interval $(-\infty,0]$.

Numerically, the blow-up occurs near $x=-0.53$.

The solution to $y'=-cy^3$ with the same initial condition blows-up at $x=-\frac 1{2c}$, so it turns out (somewhat surprisingly) that in our given ODE the $x^2$ is negligible and the solution behaves almost like $y'=-y^3$.

However, quantifying this proves difficult, because I need a lower bound on $(1-x^2/y)$ that will be valid in a large interval and yet contain the blow-up point. Any way, preferably "generalizable", to proving this?

Estimating via many short intervals again might fail because I need the approximation to be good enough, or the $1/(2c)$ will become too far away for the next approximation.

[image]